# clearInterval Javascript not working, tried two different ways

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

So I´m trying to stop a countdown when day,hour, minute and seconds are all zero.
I tried clearing the interval in two different ways, but they both don´t work.

```
function startInterval (){
    const startDate = new Date ();
    const endDate = new Date ("August 15, 2020 17:55:00");

    let timeDifferenceObj = getTimeDifference(startDate, endDate);
    timerDayEl.textContent = timeDifferenceObj.rDays;
    timerHourEl.textContent = timeDifferenceObj.rHours;
    timerMinEl.textContent = timeDifferenceObj.rMinutes;
    timerSecEl.textContent = timeDifferenceObj.rSeconds;
}

let timer = setInterval(startInterval, 1000);

function stopInterval () {
//if (timeDifferenceObj.rDays === 0 & timeDifferenceObj.rHours === 0 & timeDifferenceObj.rMinutes === 0 & timeDifferenceObj.rSeconds === 0 ){
if (startDate === endDate){        
clearInterval(timer);
    }
}

stopInterval();
```

```
let timer = setInterval(function() {
    const startDate = new Date ();
    const endDate = new Date ("August 15, 2020 17:50:00");

    let timeDifferenceObj = getTimeDifference(startDate, endDate);
    timerDayEl.textContent = timeDifferenceObj.rDays;
    timerHourEl.textContent = timeDifferenceObj.rHours;
    timerMinEl.textContent = timeDifferenceObj.rMinutes;
    timerSecEl.textContent = timeDifferenceObj.rSeconds;
    if (timeDifferenceObj.rDays === 0 & timeDifferenceObj.rHours === 0 & timeDifferenceObj.rMinutes === 0 & timeDifferenceObj.rSeconds === 0 ){
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 1000)
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: You cant compare 2 date objects with === operator

Comment: We need to see what `getTimeDifference` does. A [mcve] please.

Answer (score 0):

set your endDate as you wish.

```js
let endDate = new Date ("August 15, 2020 17:55:00");
function startInterval (){

  if((new Date ()).getTime() >=  endDate.getTime())
    {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
    


let timer = setInterval(startInterval, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue with your code is that you are comparing two date objects with "==" operator, which will not work.

---

**Solution:**

**use getTime() method** :  The getTime() method returns the number of milliseconds* since the Unix Epoch. so getTime() method will return  a number which can be compared with other numbers with "==" or ">" operator.
as I am using set-interval of 1000 millisecond, so "==" may not work, but ">=" will definitely work, so ">=" will be the best approach

---

code :

```js
var date2 = new Date ("August 15, 2020 17:55:00");

function startInterval (){
  if((new Date ()).getTime() >=  date2.getTime()){
      console.log('-- clear interval going to invoke --')
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
    


var timer = setInterval(startInterval, 1000);
```